# Remove HTML element when pasting from Word

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

I am pasting a GDoc content using "paste from word" button on the ckeditor (4.5.4) and I want to remove the extra `span` **with** `style` associated with links in the text (so that it uses my theme css).
Here is how a link is styled after pasting to ckeditor:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong" style="text-decoration:none;">
   <span style="text-decoration:underline;vertical-align:baseline;white-space:pre-wrap;">
     <span style="color:#1155cc;">
       <span style="font-family:arial;">
         <span style="font-size:14.6667px;">Neil Armstrong</span>
       </span>
     </span>
   </span>
</a>
```

I want it to be just

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong" style="text-decoration:none;">Neil Armstrong</a>
```

I tried in ckeditor profile under **Advanced options**:
[image]

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.disallowedContent = 'span {color, font*, text-decoration}';
```

This is not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up removing the code from the custom javascript configuration in ckeditor profile (picture above) (http://localhost/admin/config/content/ckeditor/edit/Full).

```
config.allowedContent = true;
config.disallowedContent = 'span {color, font*, text-decoration}';
```

I updated my ckeditor config file:
/docroot/sites/all/modules/contrib/ckeditor/ckeditor.config.js  with this:

```
 config.allowedContent = {
$1: {
    // Use the ability to specify elements as an object.
    elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
    attributes: true,
    styles: true,
    classes: true
   }   
};
config.disallowedContent = 'span; u; p h1 h2{line*,margin*}; *[dir]';
```

I added `u; p h1 h2{line*,margin*}; *[dir]` to get rid of other attributes:

```
<h1 dir="ltr" style="line-height:1.38;margin-top:24pt;margin-bottom:6pt;">Apollo 11</h1>
<p dir="ltr" style="line-height:1.38;margin-top:0pt;margin-bottom:0pt;">was the spaceflight that landed the first humans, Americans</p>
```

gives

```
<h1>Apollo 11</h1>
<p>was the spaceflight that landed the first humans, Americans</p>
```

Hope this helps  someone!

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can use https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg_filter
and configure him in /admin/config/content/ckeditor , content types

Comment: Thanks but that module is not helpful.